# Finding the dropped-on element

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm making a chess board, and am trying to find the table element that the piece is dropped on. Unfortunately, the drop event doesn't seem to be firing at all.

https://jsfiddle.net/thwee3/hhxt84k1/

```
$('.piece').draggable();
$('.pieces').droppable({
  drop: function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // should give me the number of the field
  }
});
```

This is what I have so far, can someone tell me why the drop event isn't firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div elements in the chess board squares will be zero height. So when you drop on the squares you hit the td elements - not the tiny divs.

Try adding CSS

```
.tile {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and add class tile to your divs so they become

```
<td><div id="0" class="field"></div class="tile"></td>
```

then change your code to

```
$('.piece').draggable();
$('.tile').droppable({
  drop: function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // should give me the number of the field
  }
});
```

The error you made was to assume the div elements would fill their parent. You are in good company in that. A top tip I read about debugging divs was to apply a background colour to the div so you get visual feedback that it is behaving as you expect - can be very worthwhile.

Comment: Just setting field to `height: 100%` worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great - I was a bit unclear about your class names as you mentioned 'pieces' in your question as the droppable but used 'fields' in the fiddle, so I hedged and told you to use a new one to steer you past that potential issue. Whatever - every bug you fix makes you stronger.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.piece').draggable();
    $('.field').droppable({
        drop: function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

and add this to css :

```
.field {
    height:100%;
}
```

see [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hhxt84k1/5/)

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the div it needs a height
or remove the div and use the ID and class on the td

Comment: I fixed the droppable to `.field`, but the event isn't firing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your droppable element has id="pieces", not class="pieces".

Try using #board or #pieces on your droppable element

Comment: I fixed the first error, using fields as droppables. Is droppables the ones that are dropped, or the ones that something is dropped on?